# Как узнать расположения файла на другом компе

Tags: python, файлы

Есть программа,после его запуска, должны создаться папки в которых есть файлы с  кодами . Программа заходит в папку с кодами должна открыть их и вдруг ошибка:

```
cd Code
python: can't open file 'UnShifrVirus.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'start.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Вот код, прописанный в бат файле для открытия файла:

```
cd Code
python UnShifrVirus.py
python start.py
pause
```

Все расположения файлов правильны, а также, пути к ним верны. Как решить проблему?

P.S. Все файлы находятся в zip папке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для правильной работы надо извлекать все из архива. zip при запуске cmd извлекает только сам файл cmd и его стартует.

Естественно, в Вашем случае cmd ничего не находит. Вам надо извлечь весь архив и только потом запускать cmd.

---

zip-папкой называется популярный в Windows вид архива, почитать можно [тут](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/14200/windows-compress-uncompress-zip-files)

Comment: Если внутри питоновские программы, то ничего разворачивать никуда не нужно, питон сам умеет из архива стартовать скрипты.

Comment: Ну и помимо этого такие "папки" можно монтировать в юниксах.

Comment: @0andriy у него явно Windows - bat - это команды Windows

Comment: @stackflow, спасибо - исправил

Comment: В виндовсе тоже есть монтирование, просто скрыто от пользователя.

Comment: Не знал. Спасибо за информацию, как то не встречался просто.